# Can't write JavaBeans to CSV using OpenCSV

Tags: java, javabeans, opencsv

I'm trying to write some data to a CSV file using OpenCSV. However, when I try to store the data I get a `CsvBeanIntrospectionException` followed with a `NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'Email' on class 'class SubscriberBean'`.

Here's the code of my JavaBean class:

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SubscriberBean implements Serializable {

@CsvBindByName
String Email;

@CsvBindByName
String Name;

public SubscriberBean() {}

public SubscriberBean(String email, String name) {
    this.Email = email;
    this.Name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SubscriberBean [" + "Email=" + Email + ", Name=" + Name + ']';
}

public Boolean isEmpty() {
    return (this.Name.equals("") || this.Email.equals("") || this.Name == null || this.Email == null);
}
```

and the code of how I try to store data in my csv file:

```
List<SubscriberBean>  lsb = new ArrayList<SubscriberBean>();
.
.
.

    try {
        Writer writer = new FileWriter("test.csv");
        StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();

        beanToCsv.write(lsb);
        writer.close();
    } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I checked the JavaBean class, it looks fine. The CSV code is almost the same as in the example that is provided on the opencsv website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there ;)

The apache beanutils expects your fields to start with lowercase. E.g. `email`, not `Email`, etc. This is the fixed `SubscriberBean`:

```
public class SubscriberBean implements Serializable {

    @CsvBindByName
    String email;

    @CsvBindByName
    String name;

    public SubscriberBean() {
    }

    public SubscriberBean(String email, String name) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Please note that due to the lowercase fields, I had to change the setters slightly. I added the `this` reference: `this.email = email;`

Comment: Yes, that got it to work. I was following a tutorial where the fields were uppercase. Pretty dumb mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception because of the getters and setters. They should be defined also